# XMLHTTPRequest between Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

Here is a function in javascript which is currently being used to update a database. Currently when it is run, the entire python script is outputted to the javascript function intead of just the print statement. Is it possible, without importing any extra modules, for data to be sent between these two sections of code? if so, how would I do it?

Javascript:

```
function sendmsg(){

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
                    console.log(xhttp.responseText)
                    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = '';
                }   
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", URL+'/SendMsg.py', true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
```

Python:

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import sqlite3

mydb = 'messenger.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(mydb)
cursor = conn.cursor()

print('alex')

"""
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
Sender = form.getvalue('UserName')
Reciever = form.getvalue('Class')
message = form.getvalue('Message')
val = {"Sender":Sender, "Reciever":Reciever, "message":message}
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Message (Message, SenderID, ClassID) VALUES (:message, :Sender, :Reciever)''',val)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
"""
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ive fixed this problem, There was a error in the config file of apache which didnt allow python cgi to run how it is created to run. For future, make sure that the required lines of code in the config files are uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/). You can implement a RESTful API using Django or Flask, read the HTTP request there, extract parameter and send back appropriate response.

Right now you are requesting the server to send `xhttp.open("GET", URL+'/SendMsg.py', true);` SendMsg.py and it's sending that.